# Convert Swagger JSON to WCF contracts

Tags: wcf, swagger

I have a list of service contracts created in swagger, and I am trying to create WCF contracts based on that. As I see, I can use https://editor.swagger.io to convert swagger json to asp.net core server. But I can't seem to find anything that will help me convert this json to WCF contracts.

I thought of using SwaggerWCF nuget package, but that seems to allow only the conversion of WCF contracts to Swagger JSON, not the other way around. Is there something I am missing on that nuget package?

Or maybe there is some other tool that I can use to create WCF templates from Swagger?

Answer (score 0):

you have swagger.json, you want to convert this json to WCF contracts.
1. convert json to .net class with SwaggerNet 
2. create new assembly with System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder

- https://github.com/justin0522/SwaggerNet